# iPhone Development - Compiler Warning!

Tags: iphone, compiler-construction, warnings

Sometimes when i try to "build"/compile a downloaded source, i get following warning:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Volumes/Skiiing2/CD/ViewBased/Unknown Path/System/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I just upgraded to iPhone SDK version 3.2, and ran into this problem. It looks like it happens on all my projects that were created with the 3.1.2 SDK.

After some amount of searching, I finally was able to find it in the project settings. You have to "Get Info" on the target to find it. Click the "Build" tab, and scroll down to "Search Paths". It can be deleted from there.

Comment: as of XCode 4.4, this is under the "Build Settings" tab.

Comment: Also in XCode 4.4+, check both `Library Search Paths` and `Framework Search Paths` depending on the type of missing which is reported missing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. I've found this path in search path settings but not for project but for target!

Answer (score 3):

this specific warning with the 'skiing' reference was a bug in the latest xcode beta for iPad.  make sure your running either the latest xcode beta or the latest production xcode.. you should not see that warning again.

Comment: nope - its in the production version I just DL/d and installed today!

Comment: Still there in 4.0 SDK today as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your project is set up to use a framework that was once on a removable disk of some kind, that is no longer there.  You can make the warning go away by removing that path from the linker command line, you'll find a property in the project somewhere that references it.

Comment: If you get info on the framework in Xcode, it will show you the path to the framework that the linker is trying to use. You can hit the "choose" button to set it to another path. So File-->Get Info and then hit the "General" tab. The file path is the topmost section.