# Warnings that never go away

Tags: iphone, sdk, warnings

When I build my project, I get some warnings about some missing files, but I don't really know why ...

Most are from SDK, but there's one very strange:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Volumes/Skiiing2/CD/ViewBased/Unknown Path/System/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/v6' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.2.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.2.1/v5' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.2.1/v6' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.2.1/v7' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin9/4.2.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Developer SDK 3.x/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin9/4.2.1/ppc64' following -L not found
```

I've never, never, ever had a volume called Skiiing2, can be an external linked lib or framework that now is missing ?

My app is working perfectly with those warnings ...

Any idea ???

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Development - Compiler Warning!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392286/iphone-development-compiler-warning)

Comment: yes, you're right, it's almost the same, vote for delete it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done!

the issue was the same as the linked post.