# getting error: directory not found for option

Tags: iphone, admob

I have added a iAdMob frame work to my application and copied all its files to my application. Then when I run the app it was working fine. But when I deleted the frame work from my downloads folder, it is showing the error Downloads/iAdMob/Admob is missing although I have added all the folders to my application.

Comment: This happens if you forget to check 'copy items into destination groups folder' while adding, and thus makes it to refer right from the folder where you added.

Comment: no that folder is in my app folder

Comment: Refer to this excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392286/iphone-development-compiler-warning

Comment: you should check your framework search paths in project build settings.You will have to give same path where your framework exists in xcode. Best way is add your all third party frameworks in xcode root and add /*Framework in your framework search paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove framwork from Xcode. It asks when deleting any file or folder whether you want to remove references or move to trash. Selecting "remove references" will remove references in project. Selecting "move to trash" will remove references and also remove files physically from location.